# Open MS Office files from Cordova and iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ms-office, cordova-plugins

I am using Cordova to create applications in iOS (version 10.3). I want to open an office file by using the command

```
window.open("data:application/msword;base64," + fileContent, "_blank", "location=no");
```

I use the MIME that can be found here
http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php.

I have installed plugins InAppBrowser, ADALProxy, Cordova-plugin-MS-Files.

My problem is that when the document opens, it is blank, completely empty. I can view other type of files (pdf, images etc) but not Office files (docx, xls, ppt).

Any idea? Am I missing any plugin?

Comment: how are you getting `fileContent`? inAppBrowser plugin should work if you use the file url

Comment: I am reading the file content from a webservice, by calling a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is caused by inAppBrowser not being able to view MS files.

My suggestion is to use the fileOpener2 plugin to open the file with whichever document viewer the user has that is capable of opening MS files.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/135

Then you can use something like this:

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    'YOUR_FILE_URI', // File location or URI
    'application/docx', //MIME type
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);
```

This will cause the device to use an application that can handle MS files.

Comment: I know fileopener, but it requires to provide file's URI. Existing application, gets file's content from a webservice and opens it. It would be better to stay like that.

Comment: Also, InAppBrowser is capable of opening MS files if you provide the url, but he is not providing the url, so none of them work, not InAppBrowser and not fileOpener2

Comment: Ahh. I understand better now. I will take another look and change my answer.

Comment: Actually I don't have direct access to the file's URI, I can take the content only through the webservice. I am doing the same for other files (pdf, images) and InAppBrowser can open them.

Comment: Can you link to the exact plugin you are using?

Comment: Sorry I meant the Ms file plugin.

Comment: How are you getting the base64 representation of the file? I see from the sample in the documentation it can return a file. Do you convert this to base64 yourself?

Comment: first of all, I would like to thank you for your patience. I receive binary data (fileContent) from a webservice. It is strange because for other type of files this works

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question, however I wrote a Cordova plugin to preview office document and most of major file type,

it works on IOS and Android

you can use it from here

https://github.com/mostafa-mansour1/previewAnyFile

to install in your cordova or ionic project

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-preview-any-file --save
```

then use it in your code like this

```
 PreviewAnyFile.preview("file://filepath/filename.ext");
```

if the source is base64 string then you need to save it in the device with [cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) (Write to a file) section